# While I'm debugging and clicked a button then "InvalidCastException was unhandled" is going to popup

Tags: vb.net

My code doesn't have error, but when I try to click the button this happens.
Can you guys guess what's the error?

Look at the photo

[image]

Comment: No need to guess, just read the error message. it is saying the second argument to MsgBox is not a string

Comment: Bear in mind that functions might have different overloads (e.g., different combinations of arguments). This is the case of MsgBox which has quite a few of them. Visual Studio chooses automatically the most adequate one on account of the number of arguments you type in (3 in this case). You can type "MessageBox.Show(" and in the poping-up panel click on the up/down arrows to go through all the available overloads.

Answer (score -1):

You should swap the second and third argument to your call to MsgBox.
The error occurs as the second argument should be some `MsgBoxStyle`, but you're providing a string ('iList').

Take a look at the [documention on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for more information.